# MATLAB: Finding the entry number of the first '1' in a logical array

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

I have created a logical array of 1's and 0's using the following code:

```
nWindow = 10;
LowerTotInitial = std(LowerTot(1:nWindow));
UpperTotInitial = std(UpperTot(1:nWindow));
flag = 0;
flagArray = zeros(length(LowerTot), 1);
for n = 1 : nData0 - nWindow
    for k = 0 : nWindow - 1 
         if LowerTot(n + k) < 0.1*LowerTotInitial || UpperTot(n + k) < 0.1*UpperTotInitial
             flag = 1;
             flagArray(n) = 1;
         else
             flag = 0;
         end
    end 
end
```

This returns flagArray, an array of 0's and 1's. I am trying to find the index of the first 1 in the array. ie. `1 = flagArray(index)`. I am confused as to what is the best way to accomplish this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you call an entry number is referred to as an index in MATLAB-speak. To find the index of the first matching element in an array you can use the [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html) function:

```
>> x = [0 0 1 0 1 0];
>> find(x, 1, 'first')

ans =

     3
```

Comment: Thanks again, b3! This worked wonderfully. Have a great day! -Alex

Answer (score 2):

Try this `ind = find(flagArray, k, 'first')`
with k =1

Read this [Matlab Docs - find](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html)